# What is the meaning of ‘oxyphilic’?

Tags: terminology

I read in the paper that:

> The reduction of diphenyl diselenide using lithium aluminum hydride generates a selenolate ion having Lewis acid character due to the **oxygenophilic nature of the aluminium.**

Can any one explain me the meaning of the bold expression, please

Comment: It likes to form bonds with oxygen.

Comment: Thank's Sir , but what is the type of these bonds , and which oxygen do they mean in this medium ???

Comment: Nadine if you want someone to get notified about your comment then you should add '@'  before their user id...for example @orthocresol

Comment: Ok, Sir, thank you for remarkable advice @Manshu

Comment: There is indeed no oxygen in this medium. To reveal its Lewis acid character, this compound must be transferred someplace else. Also, the word "oxygenophilic" sounds kind of old-fashioned to me.

Comment: I think it just means its attracted to oxygen, or oxygen-loving?